# Why does FuncAnimation revert back to the origin?

Tags: matplotlib, animation

I am trying to animate a sample path of Brownian motion by using FuncAnimation, but the animation keeps reverting back to the origin.

[image]

Here is my code.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

# create the time interval and partition 
t = 2.5 
n = 100 

# How many sample paths?
path_amt = 2 

# Create a brownian sample path 
def bsp(t, n): 
    dB = np.sqrt(t / n) * np.random.normal(0, 1, size=n)
    B = np.zeros(n+1)
    B[1:] = np.cumsum(dB)
    return(B)

# Simulate "path_amt" sample paths 
def sample_paths(i, t ,n):
    BSP = np.zeros((i, n+1))
    for k in range(i):
        BSP[k,:] = bsp(t, n)  
    return(BSP)

B_paths = sample_paths(path_amt, t, n)
```

This part is essentially just coming up with two independent Browinan motions. Each Brownian motion is a 1-d array of length n+1. I then store the two brownian motions in a (2, n+1) array titled B_paths, so each row represents a brownian motion. Here is the code for the animation.

```
# Create the animation function for the sample path
x = []
y = []
t_axis = np.linspace(0, t, n+1)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.set_xlim(0, 3)
ax.set_ylim(-4, 4)

line, = ax.plot(0, 0)

def anim_func(i):
    x.append(t_axis[int(i * n / t)])
    y.append(B_paths[0][int(i * n / t)])

    line.set_xdata(x)
    line.set_ydata(y)
    return line,

animation = FuncAnimation(fig, func = anim_func, \
                frames = np.linspace(0, t, n+1), interval = 10) 

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the animation is looping. Once frame reaches `t=2.5`, then it starts over, but inside your `anim_func` you don't clear `x, y`.

You can either modify this function:

```py
def anim_func(i):
    x.append(t_axis[int(i * n / t)])
    y.append(B_paths[0][int(i * n / t)])

    line.set_xdata(x)
    line.set_ydata(y)
    if i == t:
        x.clear()
        y.clear()
    return line,
```

Or set `repeat=False` in the `FuncAnimation` call.